# What does the address 0.0.0.0 exactly mean?

Tags: hadoop, bind

I read the hadoop doc and see the following set up:

```
Property name, Default value, Description

dfs.namenode.http-address, 0.0.0.0:50070, The namenode’s HTTP server address and port.
```

As I understand, the namenode http service bind to 0.0.0.0:50070, so it can handle any address with port 50070. That is to say, I can visit the http on any computer by typing "http://ipaddr:50070". But in fact I cannot visit it on any other machine different from the machine where the namenode start. Does anyone know where I am wrong? I think my understanding is wrong, but I do not know how to understand it correctly.

Comment: If the other machines are also in **same network** then you can, by typing the IP address and Port number like this :  192.168.0.1:50070

Comment: As I test, I cannot access the namenode page by typing anyipaddress+50070port in the same local area network, I still cannot understand the function of 0.0.0.0 address.

Comment: Just type Jps on the machine where you have installed hadoop and see namenode is in running Mode or not.  If it is running then you can get the same namenode UI from any machine which is in same network by typing the IPaddr:50070. Here the IPaddr means the IP of the machine wher you installed Hadoop.

Comment: According to my research , I think the 0.0.0.0 probably means that it will bind to all interfaces in one machines. Means one machine maybe have multiple network interfaces(IP addresses),  it will listen to the requests from all the interfaces. But new questions come, when we need to use 0.0.0.0 in hadoop settings?

Comment: You can refer the documentation about the name and for Port number refer Web UI section. It is not 0.0.0.0 ,  in fact it is the IP of machine where NameNode recides. Refer this  https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.5.2/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HdfsUserGuide.html